# Promise doesn't resolve a DOM element what I expected

Tags: javascript, dom, promise

I implemented a kind of logic using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to find a DOM element for the reason of DOM changes.

```
const waitForElement = async (
  selector
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(selector);
        console.log('found element=', element);

        if (element) {
          observer.disconnect();
          resolve(element);
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  });
});


waitForElement('button[data-test="node"]').then(el => {
  console.log('button element', el);
});
```

I think the page what I am on now has several iframes and has lazy load.

But I noticed that this works for only the first time specifically whenever I refresh a page.

If I check the log `found element=` inside the MutationObserver, then I can see the found element and logged that element several times, but it doesn't resolve that element as a result.

I am expecting that the `waitForElement` function should find the button element whenever the DOM changes every time.

Comment: promises do not keep returning. Once you are resolved it is done.

Comment: Promises only resolve once.  Maybe you just need that observer without the promise wrapper

Comment: ...or you may want an [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/)

Comment: I don't want to use additional library or framework. I need to focus on pure JavaScript.

Comment: And if I remove `observer.disconnect()`, then I can see the mutation observer finds the element, but still doesn't resolve.

Comment: You never call `observer.observe()`

Comment: @Barmar I know that. It doesn't matter for now. Promise doesn't resolve is a matter.

Comment: If you never call `observe()` then the callback function never runs, so it never resolves.

Comment: You have a syntax error. `});` before `waitForElement` should be just `};`

Comment: "*has several iframes*" - you realise that neither the mutation observer nor `document.querySelector` will apply to elements inside a frame, right?

Comment: "*I can see the found element and logged that element several times, but it doesn't resolve that element as a result*" - that doesn't seem possible with the code you posted. Can you please create a [mcve] that allows us to experience this problem?

Comment: "I need to focus on pure JavaScript" what do you suppose libraries and frameworks are written in? [Intercal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL)? That being said, you can write tons of bespoke JS code that half-works when the moon is waning or you can use a battle-tested library. I'm not saying never build your own but beware....

Comment: @JaredSmith I am building a chrome extension and it has a content script which should add a button to a kind of dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a promise only resolves once. You can create a new promise each time it resolves, to wait for the next one. With your code structure, you can await the promise in a loop.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const waitForElement = async(
  selector
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      const element = document.querySelector(selector);
      console.log('found element=', element.nodeName);

      if (element) {
        observer.disconnect();
        resolve(element);
      }
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true
    });
  });
}

(async() => {
  while (true) {
    let el = await waitForElement('button[data-test="node"]');
    console.log('button element', el.nodeName);
  }
})();


setInterval(() => {
  container.innerHTML = '<button data-test="node">X</button>';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically it is an existing complex website and I need to insert my custom DOM element to the resolved element. The website structure has left and right side, if I select one item from the left side list, then it requests an api and then renders right side with a lazy load.

Comment: And your code works for only first load.

Comment: My code keeps adding the element in `setInterval` loop, and the promise displays the message each time that runs.